# Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected , Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, admob

[image]

Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem? The IDE itself tells you, an Int was expected but you are passing a String.

To get values ​​from resources, for example, strings, themes, etc... you need to pass an Int or id of the resource, which is obtained by doing

```
R.id.your_resource
```

Comment: I'm using firebase databases, I read string InterstitialID = R.id.your_resource
But when this variable passes an error occurs

Comment: getString gives you a String that your string resource folder, so it must be an int, but if the value you get back is an int of its own, you don't need to get it from the resources, do you? Or what string of the resources do you expect to be fetched from that ID?

Answer (score 0):

So looking at your code:

```
val InterstitialId = dataSnapshot.child("interstitial_id").value.toString()
```

This line will return a string when you call the `.toString` method, 2 lines  below you are passing this variable to a `.getString` and according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getString(int)) `getString()` expects an Int not a String.